# HTML: Moving content overflow to a seperate div?

Tags: html

I think this is a relatively simple problem. I wish to obtain some functionality that works as follows: when one div column becomes too full, the overflow of content gets automatically moved to an adjacent div.

I wish to do this as my 3 div columns are full of hyperlinks and ordered alphabetically. At the moment they are manually entered into each column. The problem is, though, that if I wanted to add one more hyperlink to column A, for example, I will have to manually reorder all 3 columns or column A would overflow and be out of line.

Any ideas? Perhaps there is a tag or an attribute that I am unaware of?

Comment: Have you got an example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the W3C's [Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), but it isn't supported by all browsers yet.

Comment: The only browser it doesn't work in is IE but things not working in IE is normal and expected.

Comment: Sorry, I only had a quick scan over it as I'm working on my site and I thought I saw <multicol> somewhere.

I shall try that, but I know it works because of the example so you get a nice tick! :)

Comment: There once was an element named multicol, but it never made it into the official specs.

Answer (score 0):

The multi-column layout is a good thing to look at. Otherwise your only solution would be a javascript one.